# Windows Radius Server IP Setup on DC

Tags: vpn, radius, nps, rras

Attempting to setup a Radius Server for RRAS VPN connections on Windows Server 2022, the same server is also a DC. The Server internal IP is 192.168.1.2, what should the Radius Server IP address be set to?